# How do you create a directory with the same access permissions as an existing one?

Tags: c, unix, stat

I need to make a new folder that has the same permissions as another folder.
My end goal for the assignment is to copy a directory and it's contents entirely.
This is one of my first steps and I can't seem to get it to work.

What I have is below:

```
struct stat srcstat;
int srcstatus = stat(source, &srcstat);
if (chdir(dest))
    if (mkdir(dest, srcstat.st_mode)){
        printf("error: could not create <dest>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

source is a cstring with the path to the folder whose permissions I want to use.  dest is a c string with the path to the new folder.

the ls with the old and new folders permissions is below

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 kingacev CS-Majors 4096 Apr 18 17:03 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 kingacev CS-Majors 4096 Apr 18 18:12 test3
```

my first thought is that I can't use srcstat.st_mode in the way I'm attempting.  If that's the case, is there an equally simple way to do what I'm trying to do?  If not, how far from the mark am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are running foul of the "[umask](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask)", a per-process setting which *masks* out permission bits in file and directory creation operations.

There is no safe way to disable the umask.  What you should do instead is create the directory with mode zero (i.e. all access denied) and then use [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod) (the system call, not the shell command of the same name) to adjust the permissions to what you want.

Your program fragment has many other bugs.  This is tricky to get right, and might well be a security hole if you get it *wrong*, so I shall write out the correct code in detail:

```
int
make_directory_like(const char *to_create,
                    const char *prototype)        
{
    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(prototype, &st)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lstat: %s: %s\n", prototype, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (!S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lstat: %s: %s\n", prototype, strerror(ENOTDIR));
        return -1;
    }
    /* create directory initially with no perms at all - this is the only
       safe way to suppress the effects of the umask.  */
    if (mkdir(to_create, 0000)) {
        if (errno != EEXIST) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mkdir: %s: %s\n", to_create, strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        } else {
            /* check whether the thing that exists is a directory */
            struct stat st2;
            if (lstat(to_create, &st2)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "lstat: %s: %s\n", to_create, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }
            if (!S_ISDIR(st2.st_mode)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "mkdir: %s: %s\n", to_create, strerror(EEXIST));
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (chmod(to_create, st.st_mode & ~S_IFMT)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "chmod: %s: %s\n", to_create, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Exercises for you:

1. Why is this the only safe way to suppress the effects of the umask?  (Hint: threads. But that's only one of several reasons.)
2. Why do I use `lstat` rather than `stat`?
3. Why is it necessary to stat the *to-create* path if `mkdir` fails with `errno == EEXIST`?
4. Why is it incorrect to use `chdir` as you were doing?  (There are two reasons.)
5. Why is it *safe* to go ahead and call `mkdir` on the to-create path when we don't know whether there is already something there?
6. Why is that `& ~S_IFMT` thing necessary?

Comment: but my teacher specifically said to use stat, why shouldn't I.

Comment: The only reason I can think of not to use chdir is that it might move my cwd, but I use I fix that outside of the segment I posted.

Comment: The most important reason not to use `chdir` here is that using it to check whether a directory exists introduces a [TOCTOU race](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html). The second most important reason is that it may be *impossible* to restore the cwd to what it used to be (for instance, if the program was started inside a directory whose parent denies search privilege -- this is rare but not unheard of). The third most important reason is that the cwd is process state, not thread state, so in a multithreaded program, changing the working directory will interfere with other threads.

Comment: As for `stat` vs `lstat`, your teacher was probably glossing over the difference, which is subtle, but important in this scenario. That was sloppy of them.

Comment: Teachers are sometimes wrong as well, they're not gods. In SO we should have as correct and error free code as possible, irrelevant of what an individual teacher has claimed. +1 to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the `umask` to zero. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html

Otherwise, some bits (often 022, like you're seeing) will always be cleared.

```
umask(0);
```

Comment: that works.  I'm curious, do you know why it defaults to 022 and not 0?

Comment: -1: Not thread-safe under any circumstances; potentially disastrous consequences even in a single-threaded program if you forget to restore it to its original value.

Comment: would you like to propose an alternative solution?

Comment: Touché. That *is* thorough.

Comment: @d0m1n1c Years later, but for the record:  Many flavors of Unix will explicitly set `umask 022` in their central "all users run these commands automatically on login" scripts.  The idea is to mask out the bits that would grant write permission to other users, so that your files being created (potentially by software that is sloppy about permissions) aren't writable by other people by default.